# Windows installer stuck at Windows Logo

Tags: windows-10, boot, cpu, 64-bit

I currently have Windows 10 32 bit installed on my system and I now want to upgrade to Windows 10 64 bit. I have downloaded the ISO and burnt it to my USB. I boot from it and all I get is the blue Windows Logo with no spinning wheel. Mouse laser is not on, and the keyboard caps lock button doesn't respond; I am guessing the installer is stuck somewhere.

After a bit of research **I believe the problem is with my Intel Pentium D 820** (2.80 GHz) CPU. I have read recently that the CPU doesn't work with the 64 bit version of Windows 10. **Is this true, has anyone got this CPU working?**

A few things that could possibly help me:

- How to get verbose of installer boot
- Working Windows 10 64 bit on Pentium D
- Any other things to try out

*BTW I have tried it on 2 different PCs and they both worked fine*

---

## PC SPECS:

CPU: Intel Pentium D 820 (2.80 GHz)

GPU: AMD RADEON HD 4550

RAM: 2GB RAM

OS: Windows 10 32bit

Comment: It's not your CPU, it has a 64-bit instruction set. Unless it's specifically Windows 10 that doesnt like it... http://ark.intel.com/products/27512/Intel-Pentium-D-Processor-820-2M-Cache-2_80-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out: The Pentium D 800 series didn't support Windows 10 64 bit because it was missing some 64 bit instructions required for Windows 10 64 bit. However the 900 series does. So I bought a cheap Pentium D 950 and it worked.

The instruction missing was CMPXCHG16B. Without it Windows 10 64bit won't work. Anything newer than the 900 series of the Pentium D will work (Which is lucky for me as it is the highest my motherboard will take).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the answer, but I seem to be in the same situation, the main common point between my system and yours seems to be the Pentium D processor.  When I look at the Specs on the Intel page here:
http://ark.intel.com/products/27512/Intel-Pentium-D-Processor-820-2M-Cache-2_80-GHz-800-MHz-FSB
You'll see that the CPU has 32-bit memory extensions.  I'm installing a 64-bit version of the OS.  Previously I'm pretty sure I was using 32-bit version of Windows 7.  It looks like you tried the same thing 32->64 bit OS install on the same processor.  Normally I wouldn't have tried to do this, but the Wikipedia page listed the Pentium D as being a 64 bit processor.

Anyway, I hope you already figured this out, but maybe this will help anyone else that finds this page.

Comment: It says the memory allocation is 32-bit, but it has a 64-bit instruction set. Would this make a difference in compatability?

Comment: Worked it out: The Pentium D 800 series didn't support Windows 10 64 bit because it was missing some 64 bit instructions required for Windows 10 64 bit. However the 900 series does. So I bought a cheap Pentium D 950 and it worked.

Comment: @RACING121 Please convert your comment into an answer for future readers. Thanks.